# creating res.cookie in JSON format with value as object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried do create a res.cookie like this:

```
function createCookie(res, loginToken, user) {
  res.cookie(
    'testcookie',
    {
      'logintoken': loginToken.cookieValue,
      'user_id' : user.id,
      'username' : user.name
    },
    {
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 604800000),
      path: '/'
    }
  );
}
```

Then I access the cookie like this when a request comes in:

```
console.log (req.cookies)
```

I get this output:

```
 { 
   ...
   testcookie: '[object Object]'
 }
```

If I try to do:

```
  JSON.parse(testcookie)     // it errors not not being a valid JSON object
  JSON.stringify(testcookie)   // does not help either.
```

How can I send res.cookie in JSON object which I can parse later after reading from req object?

Please provide pointers?

Comment: Is that [Express](http://expressjs.com/)' [`res.cookie()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie)? If so, what version of Express do you have installed?

Comment: I am using express 2.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option of passing an `Object` to `res.cookie()` and having it auto-stringified as JSON is a [new feature of Express 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-3.x#response).

For Express 2.x, you'll need to `stringify` it yourself when creating the cookie:

```
function createCookie(res, loginToken, user) {
  var jsonValue = JSON.stringify({
    'logintoken': loginToken.cookieValue,
    'user_id' : user.id,
    'username' : user.name
  });

  res.cookie(
    'testcookie',
    jsonValue,
    {
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 604800000),
      path: '/'
    }
  );
}
```

And probably have to `parse` it yourself as well:

```
var testcookie = JSON.parse(req.cookies.testcookie);
```

Comment: @user2384694 I've also updated the 1st snippet in my answer so the differences maybe aren't so subtle.

Comment: wow...your new code works....I can access all 3 values from single cookie....if its not too much trouble what was the difference?....anyway thx a LOT!!!